# Setting custom key bindings for magnification of notebook display

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, magnification

I tried modifying the *Window* menu section of *MenuSetup.tr* file inside `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh` as follows

```
Menu["Window", 
    {
        MenuItem["Minimize", "WindowMiniaturize", MenuKey["m", Modifiers->{"Command"}]],
        MenuItem["Zoom", "ZoomWindow", MenuKey["/", Modifiers->{"Command", "Option"}]],
        Delimiter,
        Menu["Magnification", 
        {  (* added code start *)
            MenuItem["Larger", KernelExecute[AddTo[CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], Magnification] ,.2]], MenuKey["=", Modifiers->{"Command", "Shift"}], Scope->NotebookDefault],
            MenuItem["Smaller", KernelExecute[SubtractFrom[CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], Magnification],.2]], MenuKey["-", Modifiers->{"Command", "Shift"}], Scope->NotebookDefault],
            Delimiter,
            (* added code end *)
            LinkedItems[{
                MenuItem["50%", Magnification->0.50, Scope->NotebookDefault],
                MenuItem["75%", Magnification->0.75, Scope->NotebookDefault],
                MenuItem["100%", Magnification->1.00, Scope->NotebookDefault],
                MenuItem["125%", Magnification->1.25, Scope->NotebookDefault],
                MenuItem["150%", Magnification->1.50, Scope->NotebookDefault],
                MenuItem["200%", Magnification->2.00, Scope->NotebookDefault],
                MenuItem["300%", Magnification->3.00, Scope->NotebookDefault]
            }]
        }],
```

However, this does not work and I get the following error when trying to invoke "Larger" from the menu:

[image: message]

Note that the `KernelExecute[some args]` command that I have added works perfectly fine in a standalone notebook frontend and tries to mimic other `KernelExecute` commands found in *MenuSetup.tr*.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

P.S.: Replacing the `AddTo[]` and `SubtractFrom[]` commands by their explicit versions x=x+.2 or x=x-.2, does help get rid of the error message, but doesn't change the magnification itself.

Comment: AddTo and SubtractFrom can only be applied to symbols not to values.

Comment: They still do work in the frontend. Also, there are some commands like `KernelExecute[CompoundExpression[CurrentValue[SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]], CellFrame] = Inherited, CurrentValue[SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]], CellFrameColor] = Inherited]]` already in MenuSetup.tr which I tried mimicking.

Comment: `FrontEndExecute[AddTo[1, 1]]` gives an error?

Comment: I think I probably need to use some undocumented low-level commands, hard to guess since `KernelExecute[]` is not documented

Comment: @DanielHuber yes it does, but `CurrentValue[]` allows assignments of the form `CurrentValue[item]=val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more tinkering and careful mimicking of the existing code inside *MenuSetup.tr*, I finally landed on a working solution.

I have set

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>=</kbd> = zoom in

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>-</kbd> = zoom out

increment/decrement amount = 0.2 (or 20%)

```
MenuItem["Larger", KernelExecute[Block[{oldmag = CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], Magnification]}, 
                        CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], Magnification] = oldmag + .2]], MenuKey["=", Modifiers->{"Command", "Shift"}], MenuEvaluator->"System", Scope->NotebookDefault],
MenuItem["Smaller", KernelExecute[Block[{oldmag = CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], Magnification]}, 
                        CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], Magnification] = oldmag - .2]], MenuKey["-", Modifiers->{"Command", "Shift"}], MenuEvaluator->"System", Scope->NotebookDefault],
```

The key bindings used above may need to be changed depending on one's existing key bindings.

**Note:** Both `Block` and `MenuEvaluator->"System"` are crucial in the above code, otherwise Mathematica will panic. You can however drop the `Scope->NotebookDefault` option as `SelectedNotebook[]` kind of already defines the scope.